# Make Entity Framework Join table explicit, reduce code changes using partial classes and extension methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to add an additional field to an "implicit" Entity Framework join table - adding a sort key.
This will break a very large amount of code that relies on 
classA.classBs and classA.Add(itemB); etc.

Is there any route with extension methods and partial classes to minimise or remove other code changes ...

I've been trying to figure something out along the lines of...

```
public partial class ClassA {
        public IQueryable<ClassB> ClassBs
        {
           get
           {
              return this.JoinAB.Select(x => x.ClassB).OrderBy(x => x.SortKey).AsQueryable();
           }
        }
}
```

which results in "cannot be converted to a store expression" type problems, and I'm not sure how to get to the "lefthandside" end of

```
public bool ICollection<ClassA> Add(ClassB itemToAdd, int sortKey=0){
    var jab = new JoinAB{SortKey=sortKey, ClassB=itemToAdd};
    this.*leftHandSide*.Add(jab);
    return true;

}
```

So, is this possible to do at all, if so how?

Comment: The answer is unfortunately no, you have to update the usages.

Comment: There must be a route to at least do the first example correctly - getting from one end of a relationship to another as a store expression is something EF is good at!